# How to explain function template resolution?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Playing around with templates and specializations trying to understand the rules I used the following code.

```
template <typename T> // A
void foo(T);

template <typename T> // B
void foo(T *);

template <>
void foo<int *>(int *); // C

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int n=0;
    int *p = &n;
    foo(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Which version of foo would you think gets called here? I was expecting C. But that's not what happens. It's actually B. But why is that? Isn't C the best match and a specialization of B?

However, if I the change C to

```
template <>
void foo<>(int *) // C
```

or

```
template <>
void foo<int>(int *) // C
```

Then the foo() call gets resolved to C? So I'm not fully understanding the syntax and the meaning of what goes between the angled brackets in `void foo <>`.

Would appreciate somebody clarifying this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C isn't a specialization of B. The entity between the angle brackets in C, `int*`, is the value of the template parameter `T`. If you're specializing A, then `T` needs to be the same as the type of the parameter, which it is. If you're specializing B, then the parameter needs to be `T*`, not `T`.

When you change the declaration of C to

```
template <>
void foo<int>(int *) // C
```

C becomes a specialization of B but not A, by the same reasoning.

In both cases, B wins overload resolution. In the first case, there's no explicit specialization of B, so B gets called. In the second case, C, the explicit specialization of B, gets called.

Comment: Sorry for being dense. I'm still confused. I'm thrown off almost from the get-go. What does "int* is the value of the parameter T" mean? Could you please clarify?

Comment: When you specialize a template function, you're declaring the function with the values of all template parameters given. When you type `template<> foo<int*>(int*)`, what you're saying is that `T` is `int*`.

Comment: OK I think what was confusing me in your original statement is the unqualified use of the word parameter as in "If you're specializing A, then T needs to be the same as the type of the parameter, which it is. If you're specializing B, then the parameter needs to be T*, not T."

Comment: To make it clear I would just modify it by simple clarification of what parameter is being referred to, like this: "If you're specializing A, then the template parameter T needs to be the same as the type of the function parameter, which it is. If you're specializing B, then the function parameter needs to be T*, not T." I'm saying function parameter but not sure if that is the correct term. Whatever the correct term is it should be distinguished from the template parameter. Then it will be clear for someone trying to wrap their head around template specialization for the 1st time.